# Rspec issues with Devise

Tags: devise, capybara, factory-bot, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

In my `tickets_controller.rb`:

```
def create
    @ticket = @project.tickets.build(ticket_params)
    @ticket.author = current_user
    if @ticket.save
      flash[:notice] = "Ticket has been created."
      redirect_to [@project, @ticket]
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Ticket has not been created."
      render "new"
    end
```

end

So I assumed, I should be OK to pass the test, but it's giving me the errors below.

I'm under impression it's not invoking the email address from `current_user.email`...

The repo here https://github.com/tenzan/ticketee.

Deployed version here https://github.com/tenzan/ticketee

```
$ rspec spec/features/creating_tickets_spec.rb
...F

Failures:

  1) Users can create new tickets with valid attributes
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content "Author: #{user.email}"
       expected to find text "Author: test4@example.com" in "Internet Explorer Non-standards compliance My pages are ugly!"
     # ./spec/features/creating_tickets_spec.rb:36:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/features/creating_tickets_spec.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.64558 seconds (files took 1.3 seconds to load)
4 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/creating_tickets_spec.rb:30 # Users can create new tickets with valid attributes
```

**UPDATE 1:**

`show.html.erb` for `ticket`:

```
<header>
  <h2><%= @ticket.name %></h2>
  <ul class="actions">
    <li><%= link_to "Edit Ticket", [:edit, @project, @ticket],
      class: "edit" %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Delete Ticket", [@project, @ticket], method: :delete,
      data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this ticket?"},
      class: "delete" %></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<table id="attributes">
   <tr>
     <th>Author: </th>
     <td><%= @ticket.author.email %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th>Created: </th>
     <td><%= time_ago_in_words(@ticket.created_at) %> ago</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<div id="ticket">
  <header>
    <h1><%= @project.name %></h1>
  </header>
  <header>
    <h2><%= @ticket.name %></h2>
</header>
  <%= simple_format(@ticket.description) %>
</div>
```

**creating_tickets_specs.rb**:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature 'Users can create new tickets' do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do
    login_as(user)
    project = FactoryGirl.create(:project, name: "Internet Explorer")
    visit project_path(project)
    click_link "New Ticket"
  end
  scenario "with valid attributes" do
    fill_in "Name", with: "Non-standards compliance"
    fill_in "Description", with: "My pages are ugly!"
    click_button "Create Ticket"
    expect(page).to have_content "Ticket has been created."
    within("#ticket") do
      expect(page).to have_content "Author: #{user.email}"
    end
  end
  scenario "when providing invalid attributes" do
    click_button "Create Ticket"
    expect(page).to have_content "Ticket has not been created."
    expect(page).to have_content "Name can't be blank"
    expect(page).to have_content "Description can't be blank"
  end
  scenario "with an invalid description" do
    fill_in "Name", with: "Non-standards compliance"
    fill_in "Description", with: "It sucks"
    click_button "Create Ticket"
    expect(page).to have_content "Ticket has not been created."
    expect(page).to have_content "Description is too short"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things

1. After you set author on ticket, are you calling `save`?
2. What is in the show template where it's blowing up?

Typically I would write your controller code as:

```
current_user.tickets.create ticket_params
```

Which, assuming the relationships are set up correctly, will automatically set up the relationships as you would expect.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my post.
Where in the controller should I made changes you pointed above?
Can you please take a look my repo if you want to look for the other places?

Answer (score 0):

`Rspec` was looking for `"Author: test4@example.com"` within `ticket` tag as per `within("#ticket")` as described in the `creating_tickets_spec.rb`, but in my case it was out of that scope.

So, putting it inside solved the issue.